# R which() function with vectors

Tags: r

I have three vectors

```
evens <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)
r <- c(4,5,8,9,12)
t <- c(10,12)

which( evens > r)# returns to 6,7,8,9,10
which( evens > t)# returns to 7,8,9,10
```

Why are the results different?

Could you please explain how which function works?

Comment: Please review the recycling rules for R vectors.

Comment: Recycling rules: http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-lang/R-lang_41.html

Comment: I see, thank you guys! (I realize it is really a stupid question lol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have already pointed out this is due to the recycling rules of R. You can see how it works in detail by doing this:

```
> data.frame(evens, r, t, evens > r, evens > t)
   evens  r  t evens...r evens...t
1      2  4 10     FALSE     FALSE
2      4  5 12     FALSE     FALSE
3      6  8 10     FALSE     FALSE
4      8  9 12     FALSE     FALSE
5     10 12 10     FALSE     FALSE
6     12  4 12      TRUE     FALSE
7     14  5 10      TRUE      TRUE
8     16  8 12      TRUE      TRUE
9     18  9 10      TRUE      TRUE
10    20 12 12      TRUE      TRUE
```

So when you do `which(evens > r)` you get the indices of all `TRUE`s in the column `event...r` above.